# How will my apps be affected if their permissions are changed using Android 4.3 App Ops?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-app-ops

I've read that in Android 4.3 there is a new feature called `App Ops`.  See [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/25/app-ops-android-4-3s-hidden-app-permission-manager-control-permissions-for-individual-apps/) for some info.

I'm a little bit worried about how this will affect apps that rely on having permissions active.  A user could easily see this feature, go into the list, and turn off permissions without thinking about how it might affect the experience.

Will this cause apps to crash with security exceptions?  Why would Google introduce a feature that could cripple apps?  Is there anything we can do about it, as developers?

I haven't received the 4.3 OTA on my phone yet so I'm unable to do any tests as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 4.3, App Ops is a hidden feature and is not an officially supported part of Android (it currently requires a third-party app to access). This means that as developers we should not need to concern ourselves with how this affects our apps (at least not yet). I imagine if/when this feature is unhidden, Google will have convenient APIs for gracefully handling different permission states.

Until then, if you still feel the need to account for permissions at runtime, I suggest you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203668/how-permission-can-be-checked-at-runtime-without-throwing-securityexception)

Comment: "This means that as developers we should not need to concern ourselves with how this affects our apps (at least not yet)" -- you are welcome to your opinion. "if you still feel the need to account for permissions at runtime" -- App Ops does not affect permissions. If an operation is blocked by App Ops, Android still reports the app as holding the permission.