# Cannot use getSystemService("usagestats") Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to use `UsageStatsManager` with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431795/how-to-use-usagestatsmanager) SO question. My line of code is

```
  UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager=(UsageStatsManager)context.getSystemService("usagestats");
```

I also tried to use

```
  UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager=(UsageStatsManager)context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
```

Regardless of what I use Android Studio says, "Must be one of: Context.POWER_SERVICE, Context.WINDOW_SERVICE..."

After a lot of research I came to know that `Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE` is hidden, so I must add the permission

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

But still, the results are same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 13):

Must be some kind of bug in Android Studio. You can disable inspection by adding:

```
//noinspection ResourceType
UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager=(UsageStatsManager)context.getSystemService("usagestats");
```

Comment: It is not a bug in AS, `Context` wants it to be one of the constants annotated with `@ServiceName`. So it is a bug in Context.