# Why i can't see all Running Apps in Android Programmatically?

Tags: android, process, task

I'm trying to list all running Apps but i don't know why i can't do it.

When i try to run the following command, i just have mine application returned.

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> listProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Many sites tells to use

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> alltasks = am.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

But also just returned my application

Is there anything to do without root to get all task/process running ?

Comment: This does not work on newer versions of Android. I believe Lollipop onwards, or Marshmallow onwards

Comment: Is there any workaround to do it withou root ?

Answer (score 3):

As stated, getRunningTasks and getRunningAppProcesses are no longer supported starting with Android 5 (Lollipop)

For newer Android versions, you need to ask the user to grant you Apps Usage permission and then ask UsageStatsManager for the apps running in a certain period of time.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html

You have more details here:

[How to use UsageStatsManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431795/how-to-use-usagestatsmanager)

Here is a sample on how to query UsageStatsManager (credits to Cole Murray - posted in the previous link) - https://github.com/ColeMurray/UsageStatsSample

Comment: I found this answer that works to me http://stackoverflow.com/a/32366476/2697368 but i'll try your solution too

Comment: UsageStatsManager reports by week, not real-time like OP wants.