# How to get list of all running apps programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am trying this method but it is deprecated.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
    Log.e("Running task", "Running task: " + tasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString() + "\t\t ID: " + tasks.get(i).id);
}
```

Comment: not working only launcher app and app that I have developed is listing

Comment: Then i think this have the same problem as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974894/why-i-cant-see-all-running-apps-in-android-programmatically . The OP in this question, commented in one of the answers that this solved his/her problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag/32366476#32366476