# How to get Usage Access Permission programmatically

Tags: android, android-security, usagestatsmanager

My app needs to have **Usage Access Permission** in order to get information about the current running app on user's phone. I am able to successfully implement it using the following code with the help from the following link.

[Usage Access apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431795/how-to-use-usagestatsmanager)

Here is my working code

```
public void showDialog()
 {
     if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

         @SuppressWarnings("WrongConstant")
         UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService("usagestats");
         long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
         List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,
                 time - 1000 * 1000, time);
         if (appList.size()==0)
         {
             AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                     .setTitle("Usage Access")
                     .setMessage("App will not run without usage access permissions.")
                     .setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             // continue with delete
                             Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                            // intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$SecuritySettingsActivity"));
                             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                             startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                         }
                     })
                     .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             // do nothing
                             dialog.dismiss();
                         }
                     })
                     .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                     .create();

             alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
             alertDialog.show();
         }                      else {
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, PackageService.class);
             startService(intent);
             finish();
         }
     }else
     {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, PackageService.class);
         startService(intent);
         finish();
     }
 }
```

This code will show a user an alert dialog that Usage Access permission is required and will take user to the settings screen from where it can be enabled.

Everything works perfectly with this. Only thing that I want is that **how to give my app usage access permission by default without showing any dialog** to user until he/she doesn't turn it off manually?

Comment: have you found any solution for that please??

Comment: @vivek, once its turned on, how were you detecting the current app being opened in user's phone..? I mean the PackageService details

Comment: @Anukoolsrivastav can you describe more what you want to ask ?

Comment: @VivekMishra I want to write a service that will detect whenever any other app is opened/foreground in phone.

Comment: what will be the PackageService.class?

Comment: @Eshan Chattaraj Package service is a service class. I Have mentioned the link for it in the question

Comment: @VivekMishra thanks friend

Answer (score 29):

**You can simply give this Permission on the manifest, ignoring just this permission error:**

`<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>`

**Than use Following code for permission**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!isAccessGranted()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}


private boolean isAccessGranted() {
        try {
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
            int mode = 0;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS,
                        applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
            }
            return (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @samchaudhari with the given method, the user still has to open the Usage access page and turn it on manually. Does it turn it on automatically for you? without any user input?

Comment: @kash there is not any way to turn it on automatically. user must turn it on manually.

Comment: how we add tutorial screen in usage setting screen