# Why isn't my app on the list of apps to grant android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS to? I included it in my manifest file

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-settings

I included this line in manifest file

```
  <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
            tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

But when I open the Grant Usage Access section with

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
```

My app isn't even on the list of apps to grant this access to, am I missing something?

Comment: this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153556/5580210

Comment: Thanks that answer helped me check that I got the permission, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If the permission is not showing up on your list that means you didnt place your permissions in the right place in your Manifest file make sure to follow to format specified 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169294/how-to-add-manifest-permission-to-android-application)