# NetworkStatsManager: get an error when I query

Tags: android, networkstatsmanager

When I implement a network stat history, I get this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Network stats history of uid
>   -1 is forbidden for caller 10160

Here is the code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        networkStatsManager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NetworkStatsManager.class);

        try {
            Log.v("Tethering activity: ", networkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,
                    "", 0, System.currentTimeMillis(), NetworkStats.Bucket.UID_ALL));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Do you have an explanation?

Comment: Are you requesting and did you grant `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`?

Comment: I added this this to the manifest:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

Comment: But you still need to grant that permission. It's a runtime permission and isn't automatically granted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686632/how-to-get-usage-access-permission-programatically

Comment: It works! thank you!

Comment: @TheWanderer you said still need to grant that permission. How ? Im getting same error but i dont know from where i need to grant it on run time

Comment: @Bazouk55555 how it works can you guide me too thanks in advance