# Android: How to check application is Running or not

Tags: java, android, runtime

I need to check by packageName - running application or not.
Until v.21 I simply get list of running applications and dance.
But now it not working - returns only one my app.
I know that I need use "Statistics Usage", but can't find completely example for it.

I don't need all this analytics, I need one simple function

```
bool isRunning(String packageName)
```

How to implement it on new Android (>21) without dancing arround it?

## upd. Answer of code4rox the best. All is OK, thanks!

I use this code for check rights:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.app.AppOpsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import  android.provider.Settings;

try {
            PackageManager packageManager = getContext().getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(getContext().getPackageName(), 0);
            AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
            int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
            if (!(mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {}
```

And this for check app:

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager;
import android.app.usage.UsageStats;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public boolean isRunning(Context context, long timeMills, String app) {
        boolean result = false;
        //timeMils = 1000
        UsageStatsManager usm = (UsageStatsManager)context.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<UsageStats> appList = usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,  time - timeMills, time);
        if (appList != null && appList.size() > 0) {
            for (UsageStats usageStats : appList) {
                String appname = usageStats.getPackageName();
                Log.i("DOM_LAUNCHER", "Running app: " + appname);
                if (app.equals(appname)) {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4213851/7140884) answer. It does what you're looking for.

Comment: No! getRunningAppProcesses NOT WORKING in new Android. It returns only your app in list of one item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any way to get the all running apps in API level (>21) for the security reasons.

**BUT**

> You can access to app usage history and statistics with the time
>   intervals: days, weeks, months, and years with `UsageStatsManager`

Here is official Docs [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager)

The Other Apps like **clean master , ccleaner** use this technic to get running apps.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26622587/9868485) is the Example to get apps list using `UsageStatsManager`

> Note: You must give  **[Usage Access Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42153556/9868485)** before use `UsageStatsManager`

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager) documentation. Scroll down to the section of methods. Some of the methods need permission and some of them are only intended to be used only for debugging. Hope that helps.

Comment: These methods deprecated and not working many years. I need like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619349/android-5-1-1-and-above-getrunningappprocesses-returns-my-application-packag But it returns list apps that was active some mills ago, but I need a RUNNING apps

Comment: In what android version are you looking to implement the feature?

Comment: for sdk >=25 version .

Answer (score 0):

Add REAL_GET_TASKS permission in your AndroidManifest file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).