# Android How to get all list apps installed from user

Tags: android, kotlin

I have used this code to get all list apps installed from user. But this code can not get all list app installed only get a part. Examle my phone have app Facebook, Messenger, Telegram ... But this code can not get those apps.
My code:

```
private fun getInstalledApps(context: Context): ArrayList<AppInstall> {
        val mainIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
        val pkgAppsList: List<ResolveInfo> =
            context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0)
        Log.d("TEST_LIST", pkgAppsList.size.toString())
        val res: ArrayList<AppInstall> = ArrayList<AppInstall>()
        for (i in pkgAppsList.indices) {
            val name =
                pkgAppsList[i].activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.packageManager)
                    .toString()
            val drawable =
                pkgAppsList[i].activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context.packageManager)
            val bitmap: Bitmap? = drawableToBitmap(drawable)
            val idApp = pkgAppsList[i].activityInfo.packageName
            val appInstall = AppInstall(name, bitmap, idApp)
            res.add(appInstall)
        }
        return res
    }

Is there any other way to get all the apps installed on the phone ?. Thank you !
```

Comment: Did you [add a suitable `<queries>` element to your manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring?hl=en#intent-filter-signature)?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes bro 
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.action.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

Comment: But still can not get all list installed apps in phone bro

Comment: Try using `PackageManager.MATCH_ALL` flag in the `queryIntentActivities()` call, instead of passing `0` as the second parameter and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the queryUsageStats method if the [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager) which will return a list of apps over the given interval.

To do so you will need permissions for Usage Access to be set in the manifest. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686632/how-to-get-usage-access-permission-programmatically) for reference:

> android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"