# Get current app running time

Tags: android

I want to know the detail - how long has my app been active in a day ?
I cannot is explicit storing of start time and end time as the app is deployed on plug pcs (which do not have a battery, so onDestroy would not be called). 
Is there a way to get app running time information by just using system calls ?

Comment: You could use analytic tool such as Google Analytics which will do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you could do this yourself? with creating an extra background thread that runs when the `Application` singleton class starts by calling the `onCreate()` in your while loop you could add `wait` or `sleep` to your Thread for the interval you want, or you could just use `TimerTask`, store your values to your variables and persist them in sharedPreference or so, just for incase.

Then call it whenever you want.

Comment: This is what I planned to do.

Comment: so the confirmation leads to what?

Comment: Although your solution does work for sure, I have used a local sqlite db to store session history without needing another thread. Thanks though.

Comment: you are welcome sir, but if you please you could post your answer and accept it might help someone. yours seems very legit too.@jay

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code to know how time is running....

declare variables....

```
long startTime, endTime ,duration ;
```

In your onStart() Methods do this....

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
     startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

In your onStop() Methods do this....

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
   endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();   
}
```

and calculate the result.....

```
duration = (endTime - startTime);
```

Then store the duration every time and add it to others

the time in milliseconds...

Comment: Can rely on onStop, because - app is deployed on plug pcs (which do not have a battery) so cant ensure onStop will be called when device is powered off.

Comment: yeah,,,onStop will be called when device is powered off

Comment: Power off as in, power cut or connection removed abruptly.

Comment: This is an exceptional case so you can Ignore This case

Answer (score 1):

There is a [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) which is available from API level 21. It can be used to check if your app is active or get application usage stats.

> NOTE: This API requires the permission android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS, which is a system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.

**queryUsageStats**

`List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats (int intervalType, long beginTime, long endTime)`

> Gets application usage stats for the given time range, aggregated by the specified interval. The returned list will contain a UsageStats object for each package that has data for an interval that is a subset of the time range given.

Here is sample app *(found in other so question)*:

https://github.com/ColeMurray/UsageStatsSample

[How to use UsageStatsManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431795/how-to-use-usagestatsmanager)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that. 
Even so, if `onDestroy` is not going to be called (which is not reliable in any case, because it's not called every time the activity is destroyed), you could store a "start value" in the `onResume` of your main `Activity` and calculate the usage time when `onPause` is called.

Then you add this value to the total usage of the day.

Comment: As I've mentioned - the device which uses my app are plug pcs - don't have battery, they run with continuous power supply. When power off, onPause, onDestroy will not be called.