# List<UsageStats> return empty

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-package-managers

I want to get diary use for all apps installed in phone, but always an empty list is returned. Below is the code i am using.

Here app.js from react-native call apps information from native code java

```
loadApps = async () => {
    await ReturnAppsInformations.getApps()
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response); // only [] <----
      this.setState({ apps });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.warn(error);
    });
}
```

Here is my simple native code to return array with data

```
UsageStatsManager manager = (UsageStatsManager) this.reactContext.getSystemService(this.reactContext.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
List<UsageStats> stats =manager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,1729196, System.currentTimeMillis());
WritableArray list2 = Arguments.createArray();

for (int i = 0; i < stats.size(); i++) {
    UsageStats usageStats = stats.get(i);
    WritableMap appInfo2 = Arguments.createMap();

    appInfo2.putString("packageName", usageStats.getPackageName());
    appInfo2.putDouble("firsTimeStamp", usageStats.getFirstTimeStamp());
    appInfo2.putDouble("getTotalTimeInForeground", 
    usageStats.getTotalTimeInForeground());
    list2.pushMap(appInfo2);
}
promise.resolve(list2);
```

What am I doing wrong? 
This is my first app so I do not have much knowledge

3. Updated as suggested by Julien, but still results in a empty array.

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           package="com.returnappsinformations" 
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
       <uses-permission
           android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
           tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
   </manifest>
   ```

Ok, i found those gits about it...

https://github.com/mvincent7891/UsageStatsModule

https://github.com/shimatai/react-native-android-datausage

https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-android-permissions

Tonight im gonna to read them... But i belive, that resolve the problem to me!! Thanks for support!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you asked and set the necessary permissions to use `UsageStatsManager`?

`UsageStatsManager`'s [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager) states that you need to declare android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS in your Manifest and that it needs to be turned on in the Settings of your phone for your particular application.

**EDIT:**
Permission to add in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" />
```

That special permission can't be granted through the normal permissions API of Android. So you'll need to redirect your users to the Settings page where they can grant it manually. You can open the right Settings screen via the Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
```

Comment: Thanks Julien, ill do it and and I answer you!!

Comment: Hey, inserted android manifest, but only still with empty response  :(

Comment: You also need to accept the permission on your Phone. Since this is a "special" permission, there is no way to ask for it programmatically. You'll need to go to Settings => Apps & notifications => Advanced => Special app access => Usage Access (that's on a Pixel phone, it might be somewhere else on other manufacturer Settings apps)

Comment: (and sorry, I confused the permission with the Settings constant, I corrected it in my original answer)

Comment: Oh my, so is there no way to do this automatically?

Comment: I don't believe so. You can have a look at the app ActionDash that is doing what you want with a nice onboarding flow: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actiondash.playstore

Comment: Now im using a background task to save in DB the data of days... im creating a same app for different reasons :p Julien Arzul

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android resolve this!! But only for android, for while...

Answer (score 1):

you need to declare `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` in your `Manifest`

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

as well as check at run time

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Permission is not granted
}
```

for more check [How to use UsageStatsManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431795/how-to-use-usagestatsmanager)

Answer (score 0):

As @JulienArzul pointed you need to add permission `android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS` and then need to check whether you have it or not using below code:-

```
AppOpsManager appOps = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
int mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, myUid(), context.getPackageName());
return mode == MODE_ALLOWED;
```

If above condition returns false, redirect user to that permission's settings screen

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AppLockService.class);
intent.setAction(AppLockService.ACTION_START_FOREGROUND_SERVICE);
startService(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks, i see this im here

https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-android-permissions