# Android check permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am developing my project in SDK version 23 where app permissions were newly introduced.
In some guidelines they were using below code to read phone state permission is granted or not

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(serviceContext, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //Read Phone state
   }else{
}
```

But i am directly accessing `checkSelfPermission` like below

```
if(serviceContext.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      //Read Phone state
   }else{
}
```

It's working fine.
My question is what's the difference between above these codes?.which is the correct way to check for permission granted or not?

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7203752/3235048

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is what's the difference between above these codes?

None, on API 23(+) devices.

Devices running an older version of Android, however, will generate an error through when you try to call [`context.checkSelfPermission()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)) directly. This method wasn't available until **API 23**.

`ContextCompat` provides a backwards compatible way to run `checkSelfPermission()` on older APIs too. If you look at the implementation, you'll see it accomplishes this by simply delegating the call to [`checkPermission()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkPermission(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) with the app's own process parameters. `checkPermission()` has been available since very first API release and will thus work across the board.

```
public static int checkSelfPermission(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String permission) {
    if (permission == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("permission is null");
    }

    return context.checkPermission(permission, android.os.Process.myPid(), Process.myUid());
}
```

> which is the correct way to check for permission granted or not?

So, to answer this question: if you're *only* supporting devices running Android 'Marshmallow' 6.0 and newer, then you can use either approach. However, since it's more likely you also want to support some older versions of Android, **use `ContextCompat`**.

Comment: Thanks. i will use it:)

Answer (score 1):

Add This Code To Gradle

```
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
```

and Add This Code To Your Code

```
Dexter.withActivity(getActivity()).withPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA).withListener(
                            new PermissionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                                  YourCode
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {

                                }
                            }
                    ).check();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
//Requesting permission
private void requestStoragePermission(){

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
        //If the user has denied the permission previously your code will come to this block
        //Here you can explain why you need this permission
        //Explain here why you need this permission
    }

    //And finally ask for the permission
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}

//This method will be called when the user will tap on allow or deny
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    //Checking the request code of our request
    if(requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE){

        //If permission is granted
        if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            //Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission granted now you can read the storage",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this,"Oops you just denied the permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```