# Phone State permissions?

Tags: java, android, string, performance, android-activity

I had this exact same problem:

[How permission can be checked at runtime without throwing SecurityException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203668/how-permission-can-be-checked-at-runtime-without-throwing-securityexception)

For the permission to `READ_PHONE_STATE`, because I was afraid it would pull an exception for devices which don't have phone compatibility. So, as the answer suggested, I created this method:

```
   private boolean checkReadPhonePermission() {
        String permission = "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE";
        int res = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);

        return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
```

Which should return true if the device **has** phone compatability and false if it doesn't. I then wrapped this bit of code which mutes the audio if the user is on the phone, with an if statement based on what the method returns:

[image]

For some reason, when I ran this on my emulator and put a toast to see what the method returns, I got false. The emulator device **was** a phone though, so I expected it to be able to allow that permission...Why is this happening?

Comment: @downvoters Thanks for your feedback on my question! I would really appreciate it if you told me what it is about my question that you don't like, so that I can fix it in my future questions!

Answer (score 0):

> Which should return true if the device has phone compatability and false if it doesn't

Um, no.

If you want to know whether the device has telephony capability, [use `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)` on `PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Then how do I use that method suggested by inazaruk in the linked question?

Comment: So I tried doing what you said, but now, it is always true! Even on a tablet, where it is impossible to have telephone.

Comment: Here is the code I tried out: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3ab92a621d70e9e05a5c