# Android permissionCheck not working

Tags: android, android-permissions

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Code :

```
button.setOnClickListener {
var permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  toast("success")
} else {
  toast("fail")}}
```

Why does this return "fail" ?

Comment: check runtime permission only if OS version is Marshmallow or grater

Comment: For OS <  (API 23) you should always get PERMISSION_GRANTED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requesting permissions is too confusing for me, EasyPermissions solved all my problems

Manifest :

```
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.2'
```

Code :

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        toast("yes !")
    } else {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.location_perm), 1, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION )
    }}
```

worked perfect first try

Answer (score 0):

For Android `6.0+` or `targetSdk=23` you have to consider asking for run-time permissions. The permissions `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is considered dangerous so you have to ask for it at run-time. See [Normal and Dangerous Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous) for an overview.

What you have to do is to ask it at run-time e.g.

from the developer guidelines

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Read more here at [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should request the permission like:`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_CODE);` 
and you should get an answer in `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback.
Then, if the user grant the permission, at the next time you will use the `checkSelfPermission` method you will get `success`.

For more details read this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using target sdk >=23 and run app on device with api level also >=23. So since api 23 there is new flow to recive permissions. Permissions are divided into two categories, normal and dangerous. Dangerous permissions should be asked in runtime like this:
`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);`

This will show system dialog for user:
[image: Android 6.0 runtime permissions dialog]

So result of user's selections will be returned to `public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)`

With request code that you passed in ActivityCompat.requestPermissions, in my case it is MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION

Permissions' names will be in String permissions[] and user's selections will be accordingly in int[] grantResults, with can be PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED.

Also it's good to explain to user why you need that permission before asking it.

See more here:[Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can check Permission after/in Android 6.0

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int PERMISSIONS_CODE = 1001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, PERMISSIONS_CODE);

            } else {

                // You can do you operation directly. If you added permissions in AndroidManifest...
                // Or visit following link to read about permission check.
                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203668/how-permission-can-be-checked-at-runtime-without-throwing-securityexception

            }
        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[grantResults.length-1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("permission", "accepted");
            } else {
                Log.d("permission", "denied");
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            break;
    }
}

}
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

for Android 6.0 and your targetSdkVersion >=23 , you should ask permission at run time,I have two advise:
1、you can change your targetSdkVersion in model gradle file,eg:

```
targetSdkVersion=22
```

but,I don't recommend use this method.
2、this return 'fail' mean you don't have this permission，your should 
consider if your have request but user refuse，in this your can show a dialog to tell use ,why you need this perssion,and then request the permession  you want,you can use this code below：

```html
   private boolean check(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //you have this permession
            return true;
        }else{
            //don't hava permession ,you shoud check if you can request
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                //the use refuse you request this permission ,the system well't show request dialog,you shoul show a dialog tu explain why you need this permission
                //and guide he go to system setting open this permission.
            }else {
                // you can request permission direct
                //requestCode is a integer code,that you can use is in onRequestPermissionsResult
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, requestCode);

            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        //in this you can listen the request result
        if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            //user Agree permission
        }else{
            //user reject permission
        }
    }
```

I'm sorry,I only know java,so,this code is jave. hope this can help you to deal this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int CAMERA_PERMISSSION_CODE = 1;
        public static int STORAGE_PERMISSSION_CODE = 2;
        public static int FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSSION_CODE = 3;
        public static int COARSE_LOCATION_PERMISSSION_CODE = 3;
        public static int READ_PHONESTATE_PERMISSSION_CODE = 4;




 private void askForunTimePermissions() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {


            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PermissionsActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERMISSSION_CODE);

            } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PermissionsActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSSION_CODE);
            } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PermissionsActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSSION_CODE);
            } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PermissionsActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, COARSE_LOCATION_PERMISSSION_CODE);
            } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PermissionsActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, READ_PHONESTATE_PERMISSSION_CODE);
            } else {



            }


        }


    }


   @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        try {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSSION_CODE) {

                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    askForunTimePermissions();
                } else {
                    askForunTimePermissions();
                }


            } else if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSSION_CODE) {

                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    askForunTimePermissions();
                } else {
                    askForunTimePermissions();
                }


            } else if (requestCode == FINE_LOCATION_PERMISSSION_CODE) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    askForunTimePermissions();
                } else {
                    askForunTimePermissions();
                }

            } else if (requestCode == COARSE_LOCATION_PERMISSSION_CODE) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    askForunTimePermissions();
                } else {
                    askForunTimePermissions();
                }

            } else if (requestCode == READ_PHONESTATE_PERMISSSION_CODE) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    askForunTimePermissions();
                } else {
                    askForunTimePermissions();
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(PermissionsActivity.this, "No permission requests matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


//call this method where u want
  askForunTimePermissions();
```

Answer (score 0):

To check `Location` Permission via `PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission`, you need to enable Location first. Otherwise `PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission` will always return -2.