# Is there any option to check the status of accessibility permission in Android (granted to the app or not)

Tags: android, permissions, accessibility

Is there any option to check the status of accessibility permission in Android, whether it is granted to the app or not?

I tried both (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203668/how-permission-can-be-checked-at-runtime-without-throwing-securityexception) post)

```
private boolean checkWriteExternalPermission()
{
    String permission =  Manifest.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE;
    int res = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
    return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);            
}
```

and

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
int hasPerm = pm.checkPermission(
    android.Manifest.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE, 
    context.getPackageName());
if (hasPerm != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   // do stuff
}
```

but in both cases, the result is negative irrespective of permission status. Even if the service is using the permission, the result is -1.

***Please check the comments for the correct answer***, as the question can not receive answers while being closed. Thanks to abdu and Duna.

Comment: `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);` [read](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: I have tried this , but it returns -1 irrespective of the status (i used  Manifest.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE)

Comment: public static boolean isAccessibilityEnabled(Context context, String id) {
        AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
        List<AccessibilityServiceInfo> runningServices = am.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK);
        for (AccessibilityServiceInfo service : runningServices) {
            if (id.equals(service.getId())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
}

Comment: Could you post this as an answer please

Comment: This question should've never been closed. This question is, by no means, related to the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Duna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843001/duna) and [Abdu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3427883/abdu) for the answers they dropped on the comments as the question was closed once.

from the comment posted by [Abdu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3427883/abdu)

```
public static boolean isAccessibilityEnabled(Context context, String id) { 
    AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);    
    List<AccessibilityServiceInfo> runningServices = am.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK); for         

    (AccessibilityServiceInfo service : runningServices) { 
        if(id.equals(service.getId())) { 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 
        return false; 
    }
```

and from link provided by [Duna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843001/duna)
[github.com/parthdave93/AccessibilityServiceExample](https://github.com/parthdave93/AccessibilityServiceExample)

```
public static boolean isAccessibilitySettingsOn(Context mContext) {
int accessibilityEnabled = 0;
//your package /   accesibility service path/class
final String service = "com.example.sotsys_014.accessibilityexample/com.accessibilityexample.Service.MyAccessibilityService";

boolean accessibilityFound = false;
try {
    accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(
            mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);
    Log.v(TAG, "accessibilityEnabled = " + accessibilityEnabled);
} catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: "
            + e.getMessage());
}
TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter mStringColonSplitter = new TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter(':');

if (accessibilityEnabled == 1) {
    Log.v(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILIY IS ENABLED*** -----------------");
    String settingValue = Settings.Secure.getString(
            mContext.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
    if (settingValue != null) {
        TextUtils.SimpleStringSplitter splitter = mStringColonSplitter;
        splitter.setString(settingValue);
        while (splitter.hasNext()) {
            String accessabilityService = splitter.next();

            Log.v(TAG, "-------------- > accessabilityService :: " + accessabilityService);
            if (accessabilityService.equalsIgnoreCase(service)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "We've found the correct setting - accessibility is switched on!");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    Log.v(TAG, "***ACCESSIBILIY IS DISABLED***");
}

return accessibilityFound;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code for checking the permission status to your app. (here for write permission to external storage).

```
if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                //Permission Granted
                Log.v("LOG", "Permission is granted ");
                return true;
            }
            else{
                //Request For Permission
                Log.v("LOG","Permission is Revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
```

If the permission is revoked then use this override method

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Log.v("LOG", "Permission: " + permissions[0] + "was" + grantResults[0]);
            //resume task needing this permission
        }

    }
```

Comment: These methods arent working with accessibility permission

Comment: Here it is a solution for this special permission: https://github.com/parthdave93/AccessibilityServiceExample

Comment: thanks, i wish it was in the answers section.